# How Do I Select Everything In a Text Field With WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testing

I am testing a webpage which has a counter in a reason field and a previous reason in the reason field. If I do a `field.clear();` the counter is not reset. So I am trying to do the following:

```
    int reasonPriorCount = reason.getText().length();
    reason.click();
    reason.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ARROW_RIGHT.equals(reasonPriorCount), Keys.DELETE));
```

Where the `reasonPriorCount` is the length of the number of characters in the field. Since the counter is only responding to `Change` or `KeyPress` I am attempting to send the number of right arrow keys equal to the `reasonPriorCount`.

However `Keys.chord` is complaining about the the `reasonPriorCount` argument in the right arrow key press.  Is there a way to do what I need to do? Am I going about this the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is what I did to make this work:

```
int reasonPriorCount = reason.getText().length();
int i = 0;
reason.click();
while(i < reasonPriorCount)
{
  reason.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.SHIFT, Keys.ARROW_RIGHT));
  i++;
}
reason.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.BACK_SPACE));
```